# Maintain VoIP socket on WiFi reconnect, and device restart (iOS)?

Tags: iphone, ios, sockets, wifi, voip

I have a VoIP socket setup, it works properly even in suspended states, and pings server in every 10 minute.

But when the WiFi connection has broken, then I have no idea how to reconnect to the service, even in suspended state. The same goes for device restart.

Any experiences?

Answer (score 3):

1. **Bad WiFI**: iOS doesn't let you choose the network to bind to your socket, meaning:

   - If the device has only 2G/3G/4G network, it will bind your socket over it.
   - If you also has WiFi (also broken WiFi) it will bind your socket over it even though its bad for you.
2. **Reconnecting**: You may use your 10 minutes KeepAlive block in *UIApplication* in order to try and fix your connection every 10 minutes: Wake up every 10 minutes and try to reconnect.
3. **App launched automatically**: After device reboot, VoIP app DOES get to run, if it ran before the reboot. (This VoIP app privilegue also launch your app after a crash)
4. **Note**: You can detect if you were launched automatically by asking *UIApplication* its applicationState, in *applicationDidFinishLaunching*.
5. **Tip**: Use *Background tasks* while performing actions at background.
6. **Links:**

   - [Documentation at Apple's](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)
   - [Relevant thread: VOIP app behavior at background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8746599/setkeepalivetimeout-ios-behavior-exceeded-15-wakes-in-300-sec/9698212#9698212)
   - [Relevant thread: iOS Voip Socket will not run in background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601536/ios-voip-socket-will-not-run-in-background/7057169#7057169)

Answer (score 0):

Well if the device gets restarted there is no way to start your app again. The user will have to start your app.

When you connection get dropped, due to som kind of netwerk error and your app is running in the background iOS will suspend your app. Thus the user will have to start the app again to get this working.

Comment: I've heard something that iOS do something with the registred/maintained VoIP sockets on restarting.

Comment: So you say there is no way to achieve stuff like above?

Comment: Suspending app is not a problem. My app is in suspended mode, but VoIP callbacks get invoked. I'm just wondering if there's something similar with Reachability framework, or so.

Comment: the docs state that voip apps will be restarted if they exit with non zero status

Answer (score -1):

**setKeepAliveTimeout:handler:**

Configures a periodic handler for VoIP applications.

- (BOOL)setKeepAliveTimeout:(NSTimeInterval)timeout handler:(void (^)(void))keepAliveHandler

Parameters

timeout

The maximum interval (measured in seconds) at which your application should be woken up to check its VoIP connection. The minimum acceptable timeout value is 600 seconds.
keepAliveHandler
A block that performs the tasks needed to maintain your VoIP network connection. Setting this parameter to nil releases the current handler block and prevents UIKit from scheduling the next wake.

Return Value

YES if the handler was installed or NO if it was not.

Discussion

A voice-over-IP (VoIP) application can use this method to install a handler whose job is to maintain the application’s network connection with a VoIP server. This handler is guaranteed to be called before the specified timeout value but may be called at a slightly different time interval in order to better align execution of your handler with other system tasks, and thereby save power. Your handler has a maximum of 10 seconds to perform any needed tasks and exit. If it does not exit before time expires, the application is suspended.

Timeout values and handlers are not persisted between application launches. Therefore, if your application is terminated for any reason, you must reinstall the handler during the next launch cycle.

For calls to this method to succeed, the application must have the voip value in the array associated with the UIBackgroundModes key in its Info.plist file. Calling this method replaces the previously installed handler and timeout values, if any.

Availability

Available in iOS 4.0 and later.

Declared In

UIApplication.h

Comment: This is just a copy-paste from the documentation, please include a link to it as well