# Not getting reachability Call back after coming from airplane mode

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, voip, reachability

Brief: I have a iOS app that is marked as a VoIP app in its properties and I have marked the input and output streams as VoIP.  With VoIP sockets connected on 3G, if we go into airplane mode and off, we will only get network unreachable call back and not reachable call back. [it works fine in WiFi]

Detailed:
The VoIP app is pushed to background and when airplane mode is switched on [was only in 3G], we get Socket error and shortly we get network unreachable call back. When airplane mode is switched off , we expect the reachability call back to indicate to app that network is back up but it never comes. This Scenario however works perfectly fine with Wifi only or Wifi and 3G.

Any suggestions?.

Answer (score 0):

This is something that trips up many developers. If the application is monitoring reachability changes, the [handler](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/setKeepAliveTimeout:handler:) is only invoked when a reachability change takes place **if the VoIP socket was connected when the application was pushed to the background**. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080393/ios-voip-app-sleeps-reachability-has-changed-can-i-get-notification/10533041#10533041) goes into more detail about this issue.