# Skype push notification "[person] is calling..." disappears when call ends - how to do that?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, notifications, push

If iPhone is locked and somebody calls on Skype, push notification appears.
I think it's simple push notification as other app servers send.

But when the call ends (and we didn't respond, so the call is missed) push notification disappears from lockscreen! It is not stored in notification center nor recent notifications list on lockscreen.

So how to do this?
How to implement **calling of push notifications**?

Does Skype have special priveleges or is it also available for regular developer to implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No they don't. `Skype` uses voip and `Apple` allow apps that use location, voip and audio to run in background, so `Skype` is set in the `AppName-Info.plist` file `Required background modes` to `voip` and what you see is not a push notification, but a local notification controlled by the running app.

Comment: Thanks, what if you restart device (so Skype is unloaded) and receive notification (from server as Skype is unloaded) ? - or maybe Skype loads automatically as 'voip daemon' and still deals with local notifications ?

Comment: Take a look at this, this is explained in more detail: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7393083/1228534

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
```

It will remove notification. So any app can do it.

Comment: Actually I don't think it's good workaround because after Skype hides the notification it also sets badge to [1] (or more if some other events are pending) due to missed called event. - but maybe Skype fires setNotificationBadgeTo:0 and then instantly fires setNotificationBadgeTo:1 ?