# Connection state and handling over XMPP when app is in background

Tags: ios, sockets, xmpp

I have a ios application,can send/receive messages to/from xmpp server.
3 main states of the app are:

1. If this app is active,it maintains a persistent connection to the server,and it send/receive messages through this contention.
2. If this app is exited,the connection was disconnect; the xmpp server can push messages to this user's iphone via  APNS.
3. If the app switch to background , but not exited;  the connection is not disconnect,the xmpp server can also send messages to this app, but this app can receive these messages until switching to active.

WRT the 3 states, I have a question:
When the app switch to background ,the connection is not disconnect, can the app receive these messages,then notify user via local notification? 
If possible, how can I do? or,in this situation ,should I notify user via APNS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, when the app switches to background, the connection is lost after a few seconds/minutes. Unless you have marked your app to support VOIP.

Maybe you can go through the below links :

- [How to handle socket connection's events when app is in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032745/how-to-handle-socket-connections-events-when-app-is-in-background)
- [How can an iOS app keep a TCP connection alive indefinitely while in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5840365/how-can-an-ios-app-keep-a-tcp-connection-alive-indefinitely-while-in-the-backgro)